# Updating column using data.table when using global variable as column name

Tags: r, data.table

I am attempting to update a column in a data.table based on if the values in the column match an external variable. The issue I am running into is using a global variable as a column name in data.table syntax.

Specifying the column name explicitly works as expected and updates the column.

```
dt[,`1:4880` := ifelse(`1:4880`==allele, 2, 1)]
```

However, I am unable to update the column when referring to it by a variable:

```
colname="1:4880"
dt[,..colname := ifelse(..colname==allele, 2, 1)]
```

Instead of updating the values in the column described by the variable name, the output is written to df$..colname instead. Strangely, the output is correct so the ifelse function is working as intended, it's just writing the output to the wrong column name.

Is there a way to make the := operator recognize a column name specified as a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `lhs`, we can wrap with `()` to evaluate the value and either use `get` or specify it in `.SDcols`

```
dt[, (colname) := ifelse(.SD[[1]] ==allele, 2, 1), .SDcols = colname]
```

It is not clear whether the `allele` is another column or an object created with some value

Comment: The solution you provided works. Thank you! To clarify `allele` is just set to a character variable.